# Get data from a different site collection using ajax - Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, cross-site

I am trying to get some data, into a webpart in SiteA, from a document library in SiteB using an ajax call. When I added my code to a content editor it worked properly. However when added it to the webpart it didn't work. 
Here's my code :

```
function GetBalance(LoginName) {

var listName = "ListName";
var site = "SiteB";

var Local_Global_Balance;

var Ownurl = site + "_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('"+listName+"')/items?$select=VirtualBalance&$filter=EmployeeName eq '" + LoginName + "'";
 $.ajax({
    url: Ownurl,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        if (items[0].VirtualBalance != "" ) {
            itemId = items[0].VirtualBalance;
            Local_Global_Balance = itemId;
            $("#userbalance").val(Local_Global_Balance);
        }
        else {
            $("#userbalance").val("0");
        }


    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("An error occurred. Please try again.");

    }
});}
```

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: What kind of webart are you trying to add it to? Also, did you include <script type="text/javascript> </script> tags around your code?

Comment: visual web part created in visual studio and deployed in the SiteA